# Docker Desktop Mac: No space left on device, Postgres

Tags: postgresql, macos, docker, docker-compose

I know there are many similar questions on this topic. Nothing so far has helped.

Recently I added a new migration file to my Node project and its causing Docker to give the following error during integration tests

`- could not create file "base/12379/270766": No space left on device`

Specifically, it looks like it's erroring when trying to add a UNIQUE constraint to two columns.

Here's my compose file:

```
version: '2.1'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    container_name: web_1
    env_file:
      - ./local.env
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: development
      ECHO_SQL: ${ECHO_SQL}
    ports:
      - "4000:4000"
```

And here's the test compose file:

```
version: '2.1'
services:
  web:
    env_file:
      - ./local.env
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: test
      NO_SERVER: 1
      XUNIT_FILE: output/xunit.xml
    volumes:
      - ./output:/opt/app/output
    links:
      - "pg"
  pg:
    image: postgres:9.5
    command: postgres -c logging_collector=off -c log_min_error_statement=error -c fsync=off -c full_page_writes=off -c synchronous_commit=off -c archive_mode=off
    tmpfs:
      - /var/lib/postgresql/data:rw
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: mysecretpassword
```

And I run the tests with

```
$ docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose-test.yml build
$ docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose-test.yml run web bash -c "./tools/wait-for-pg.sh; grunt"
```

### Things I've Tried:

**Disk Space**

Other answers have mentioned running out of space on the actual drive. I have a ton of space left on my machine.

[image: Free hard drive space]

**Increasing Disk Size**

Increased "Disk image size" from 64G to 128G

[image: Docker desktop preferences]

I then restarted docker desktop. No effect.

**Restart**

Just in case, I rebooted my laptop after the disk image size change. No effect

**Prune**

`docker system prune --all`

Still get the same error.

**Deleting The Docker VM File**

`rm ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/vms/0/data/Docker.raw`

and then restarting Docker Desktop. Still get the same error.

**storage_opt**

I tried adding `storage_opt` to my docker compose file under the pg service.

```
  pg:
    image: postgres:9.5
    command: postgres -c logging_collector=off -c log_min_error_statement=error -c fsync=off -c full_page_writes=off -c synchronous_commit=off -c archive_mode=off
    tmpfs:
      - /var/lib/postgresql/data:rw
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    storage_opt:
      size: '1G'
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: mysecretpassword
```

docker-compose gives me this error:

`services.pg Additional property storage_opt is not allowed`

Not sure what's going on here. I read the spec: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#storage_opt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. The root cause was the use of `tmpfs`.

Using `tmpfs` for the Postgres data directory drastically speeds up the tests. However, it has a base size of 200mb which is **NOT** changed by any of the settings listed in any of the other questions.

To increase the size of the `tmpfs` change

```
  pg:
    image: postgres:9.5
    command: postgres -c logging_collector=off -c log_min_error_statement=error -c fsync=off -c full_page_writes=off -c synchronous_commit=off -c archive_mode=off
    tmpfs:
      - /var/lib/postgresql/data:rw
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: mysecretpassword
```

to

```
  pg:
    image: postgres:9.5
    command: postgres -c logging_collector=off -c log_min_error_statement=error -c fsync=off -c full_page_writes=off -c synchronous_commit=off -c archive_mode=off -c log_temp_files=10240
    volumes:
      - type: tmpfs
        target: /var/lib/postgresql/data:rw
        tmpfs:
          size: 4294967296
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: mysecretpassword
```